# Bootstrap 4 - collapse not working

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I installed Bootstrap4.0.0-beta.2 and popper and jQuery. Now I cannot figure it out why my navbar doesn't work. I mean it shrinks to responsive size but button doesn't have function.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here is an image of what does it do. I am really confused and kinda stuck. Even when i click on the button it does nothing.

[image]

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please. Are you getting any errors in the develop tools console? And what is popper?

Comment: Did you include Bootstrap Javascript?

Comment: I did. But i guess in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to include your css file. You should have something like this in your code:

```
<link href="/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

You also don't have any "functions" because your href is "#"

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
```

To make your links work, just change "#" to something else like this:

```
href="https://stackoverflow.com/"
```

Comment: Thank you. I just needed to fix the order of included files.